# Jquery.datatables shows grid and alternating color lines- but not search or page numbers

Tags: jquery, datatables

have used jquery.datatables in the past ,succesfully. In the current application, Jquery.datatables shows  grid and alternating color lines- but not search or page numbers.

Using in asp.net core 2 application.

Tried both CDN and local references.

Anybody else finding this behaviour?

Here is code in my index.cshtml page

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js "></script>

<h2>Index</h2>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-primary list-panel" id="list-panel">
      <div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
        <h1 class="panel-title list-panel-title">Service Requests</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <table id="ServiceRequests-data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">

          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                RequestHeading)
              </th>
              <th>
                RequestDescription)
              </th>
              <th>
                File Name
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </table>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>






<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#ServiceRequests-data-table').DataTable({
      "order": [
        [1, "desc"]
      ]

    });

  });
</script>
```

Actually when I got rid of all the razor stuff the stackoverflow html renderer showed the search box and page numbers. So it must be something in my razor code that is incompatible.

Comment: Please remove all the Razor code so we can run this in browser as a [mcve]

Comment: Would that be just the asp-actions stuff and @model and viewdata stuff?

Comment: Right...anything that isn't valid html and some dummy text instead of server output methods